# How to convert different strings to date time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 that stores date/time values as varchar(max) (don't ask). I've been tasked with converting these values from PST to GMT. The values are in one of two formats in each row:

Mar 12 2009 4:00PM

OR

3/12/2009 4:00:00PM

How can I, using T-SQL, determine which format the date is in (I'm thinking maybe check to see if it starts with a character or a numeric value) then convert that to a SQL datetime variable so that I can use DATEADD to add hours to it?

I've already written the T-SQL to create a cursor and loop through the rows, I'm just not sure how to detect which format it's in and then convert to DATETIME. I'm sure could probably hack it, but I figured the folks here at SO could provide me with a CORRECT way to do it.

Comment: Are you personally convinced that they will definitely be in one or other format or does this need checking too?

Comment: I'm convinced its in one of these two formats. This is a one-time data update we're running and I've looked through all of the data. There are no other formats except for these two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `convert` function which will work for both the scenarios

```
 SELECT convert(datetime, '3/12/2009 4:00:00PM') -- 2009-03-12 16:00:00.000

 SELECT convert(datetime, 'Mar 12 2009 4:00PM')  -- 2009-03-12 16:00:00.000
```

then you can format it as you like

Comment: This is the best way to do the conversion. As for how to update the rows, you mentioned using a cursor to loop through them. It would be faster (and arguably more "SQL-like") instead to use say an `UPDATE` statement. Assuming you have the strings in a column `old` and wanted the true `datetime` values to go in a column named `new`, you would do e.g. `UPDATE yourtable SET new = convert(datetime, old)`.

Comment: @Massimiliano Your solution works fine for any date which has both month and day less than or equal to 12. However it gives error in either case like if I write `SELECT convert(datetime, '13/12/2009 4:00:00PM')`, it will give an error of out-of-range value but will run fine for `SELECT convert(datetime, '12/13/2009 4:00:00PM')`. So how to cater this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me, no looping or cursors required:

```
DECLARE @Date varchar(MAX)

SET @Date = 'Mar 12 2009 4:00PM'

SELECT DATEADD(hh,8,CONVERT(DATETIME,@date))

SET @Date ='3/12/2009 4:00:00PM'

SELECT DATEADD(hh,8,CONVERT(DATETIME,@date))
```